# Determining which entities caused a Doctrine UniqueConstraintViolationException

Tags: php, doctrine

When flushing multiple persists, is there any way of determining the entities that were responsible for a `UniqueConstraintViolationException`?

```
$entityManager->persist($entity1);
$entityManager->persist($entity2);
$entityManager->persist($entity3);
...

$entityManager->persist($entity100);

try {
    $entityManager->flush();
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
    // Which entities were responsible for the violation?
}
```

I appreciate I can flush after every persist, but I'm batching them to reduce calls to the DB.

Comment: Are you using Doctrine within Symfony? I think the profiler should show this

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am yes, inside a Symfony Console app. I'm able to determine the entities from the profiler but I'm looking for a code-based solution so that I can recover from the error.

Comment: Oh, of course. I should have assumed that to begin with, sorry.

Comment: You could use the [`UniqueEntity`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint in your entity, and validate each entity - persist if it passes and handle it accordingly if it fails?

Comment: @Don'tPanic No problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: @DarraghEnright would that not require a single trip to the DB for every entity? I'm looking to do a batch insert (100 records, rather than the 3 in my example), where every trip counts!

Comment: It would, and that's probably a dealbreaker alright!

Comment: Looking at Doctrine's guts here - `BasicEntityPersister::executeInserts()` seems to be the object responsible for inserting data. There's a call to `$stmt->execute()` which throws an exception if there's a problem - an Integrity constraint violation in this case. I don't see any way here to determine which specific entity is problematic, beyond somehow using the detail in the underlying driver error message somehow...

Comment: @Jonathan - how are you creating/populating the entities?